# How to create a Spring boot application with Azure Event Hubs

Tags: spring-boot, azure

when my application when running it hit the error
All classes in my application can see below

any aides for fix this error

only 3 class available in my project.

```
 Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eventHubChannelProvisioner' defined in com.azure.spring.eventhub.stream.binder.config.EventHubBinderConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'eventHubChannelProvisioner' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.azure.spring.integration.eventhub.factory.EventHubConnectionStringProvider' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

how to fix this my main class

```
import com.azure.spring.integration.core.EventHubHeaders;
import com.azure.spring.integration.core.api.reactor.Checkpointer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

import static com.azure.spring.integration.core.AzureHeaders.CHECKPOINTER;

@SpringBootApplication
public class EventHubsCheckerApplication {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventHubsCheckerApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EventHubsCheckerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<String>> consume() {
        return message -> {
            Checkpointer checkpointer = (Checkpointer) message.getHeaders().get(CHECKPOINTER);
            LOGGER.info("New message received: '{}', partition key: {}, sequence number: {}, offset: {}, enqueued time: {}",
                    message.getPayload(),
                    message.getHeaders().get(EventHubHeaders.PARTITION_KEY),
                    message.getHeaders().get(EventHubHeaders.SEQUENCE_NUMBER),
                    message.getHeaders().get(EventHubHeaders.OFFSET),
                    message.getHeaders().get(EventHubHeaders.ENQUEUED_TIME)
            );
            checkpointer.success()
                    .doOnSuccess(success -> LOGGER.info("Message '{}' successfully checkpointed", message.getPayload()))
                    .doOnError(error -> LOGGER.error("Exception found", error))
                    .subscribe();
        };
    }
}
```

controller class

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Sinks;

@RestController
public class EventProducerController {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventProducerController.class);

    @Autowired
    private Sinks.Many<Message<String>> many;

    @PostMapping("/messages")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendMessage(@RequestParam String message) {
        LOGGER.info("Going to add message {} to sendMessage.", message);
        many.emitNext(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build(), Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(message);
    }
}
```

configuration class

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Sinks;

import java.util.function.Supplier;

@Configuration
public class EventProducerConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventProducerConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    public Sinks.Many<Message<String>> many() {
        return Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
    }

    @Bean
    public Supplier<Flux<Message<String>>> supply(Sinks.Many<Message<String>> many) {
        return () -> many.asFlux()
                .doOnNext(m -> LOGGER.info("Manually sending message {}", m))
                .doOnError(t -> LOGGER.error("Error encountered", t));
    }
}
```

pom file

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.contoso</groupId>
<artifactId>event-hubs-cheker</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>event-hubs-cheker</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-eventhubs</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

how to run with out any error i cant fix this help me for that please

how to fix this issue i try to fix this but i cant fix it

Answer (score 1):

After following the instructions on the following web page: [How to create a Spring Cloud Stream Binder application with Azure Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-cloud-stream-binder-java-app-azure-event-hub)

I was able to have the project working. You can review my implementation at the following GitHub repository: https://github.com/esalomon/spring-event-hubs1